# beamer output shifted down and to the right

Tags: beamer

Immediately after installing a TeX system on a Windows7 box, beamer functions correctly.  However, after a short while, it begins to shift all the output down and to the right.  I'd be deeply grateful if anyone else has experienced this and successfully beaten the problem into submission.

Even a simple .tex file such as this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Hello
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

when run through pdftex, compiles but the output is now shifted down and to the right:

[image]

This problem persists on multiple win7 machines, with MikTeX 2.9 and TeXLive 2012/2013 installations.  The only solutions I have found are to blow the TeX install and rebuild it, but as you might guess this is not an attractive solution.  I'm assuming that something in the configuration system of the larger TeX system has gone bonkers and is forcing beamer to move its output.

The .log file is too long to usefully append, but after ~800 lines of loading this and that, it complains:

```
LaTeX Info: Redefining \includegraphics on input line 7.
 (C:\temp\test.nav)

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmss/m/n' in size <4> not available
(Font)              size <5> substituted on input line 10.


Overfull \hbox (88.28987pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
[]
 []


Overfull \hbox (88.28987pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
[] 
 []

[1
```

Thanks for looking, Mr. Wright.  The file list from \listfiles is

```
beamer.cls    2013/04/04 3.27 A class for typesetting presentations (rcs-revision dca7db0ccda1)
beamerbasercs.sty    2013/04/04 (rcs-revision 7b8d65c07caf)
beamerbasemodes.sty    2012/04/15 (rcs-revision cc6557182d97)
beamerbasedecode.sty    2010/05/01 (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
beamerbaseoptions.sty    2013/03/10 (rcs-revision 47431932db0d)
keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
geometry.sty    2000/06/28 v2.3 Page Geometry
geometry.cfg
size11.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
pgfsys.sty    2010/06/30 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.37)
pgfrcs.sty    2010/10/25 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.24)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
pgfrcs.code.tex
pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2008/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
pgfcore.code.tex
xxcolor.sty    2003/10/24 ver 0.1
hyperref.sty    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2012/04/25 v1.12 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2012/04/25 v1.12 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
hobsub.sty    2012/04/25 v1.12 Construct package bundles (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
bitset.sty    2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
hopatch.sty    2011/06/24 v1.1 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2011/01/30 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
hycolor.sty    2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
auxhook.sty    2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
pd1enc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
url.sty    2006/04/12  ver 3.3  Verb mode for urls, etc.
hpdftex.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
beamerbaserequires.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbasecompatibility.sty    2012/05/01  (rcs-revision 67c48b3b652d)
beamerbasefont.sty    2013/06/04  (rcs-revision e18016724886)
amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
sansmathaccent.sty    2013/03/28
filehook.sty    2011/10/12 v0.5d Hooks for input files
beamerbasetranslator.sty    2010/06/11  (rcs-revision 85fd1cc7fc42)
translator.sty    2010/06/12 ver 1.10
translator-language-mappings.tex
beamerbasemisc.sty    2012/02/24  (rcs-revision 2ff5461be705)
beamerbasetwoscreens.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbaseoverlay.sty    2012/11/11  (rcs-revision 6afbc49b1109)
beamerbasetitle.sty    2010/09/21  (rcs-revision f0446ed0b6ae)
beamerbasesection.sty    2013/06/07  (rcs-revision 60b9fe0f342f)
beamerbaseframe.sty    2013/03/31  (rcs-revision edcfd2d0f22d)
beamerbaseverbatim.sty    2012/08/30  (rcs-revision dfdb135076b3)
beamerbaseframesize.sty    2011/09/12  (rcs-revision 70f9d8411e54)
beamerbaseframecomponents.sty    2012/09/13  (rcs-revision dcd846607320)
beamerbasecolor.sty    2010/06/06  (rcs-revision d1a9b48be06d)
beamerbasenotes.sty    2012/12/19  (rcs-revision 1686da3db3c9)
beamerbasetoc.sty    2013/05/23  (rcs-revision 0fdf5bc43be8)
beamerbasetemplates.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty    2013/02/02  (rcs-revision f179744ff1e3)
beamerbaseboxes.sty    2012/05/13  (rcs-revision 56972908a390)
beamerbaselocalstructure.sty    2012/11/13  (rcs-revision ddfba79dac19)
enumerate.sty    1999/03/05 v3.00 enumerate extensions (DPC)
beamerbasenavigation.sty    2013/04/04  (rcs-revision 905a39e12b38)
beamerbasetheorems.sty    2010/06/06  (rcs-revision 7e7cc5e53e9d)
amsmath.sty    2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features
amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d
amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
amsthm.sty    2004/08/06 v2.20
beamerbasethemes.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerthemedefault.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamerfontthemedefault.sty    2012/12/19  (rcs-revision 1686da3db3c9)
beamercolorthemedefault.sty    2012/12/19  (rcs-revision 1686da3db3c9)
beamerinnerthemedefault.sty    2012/05/01  (rcs-revision 67c48b3b652d)
beamerouterthemedefault.sty    2012/12/19  (rcs-revision 1686da3db3c9)
beamerthemeWarsaw.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamerinnerthemerounded.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamerouterthemeshadow.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamerouterthemesplit.sty    2012/10/16  (rcs-revision 51a8c72084af)
beamercolorthemeorchid.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamercolorthemewhale.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
 babel.sty    2008/07/08 v3.8m The Babel package
bblopts.cfg    2006/07/31 v1.0 MiKTeX 'babel' configuration
english.ldf    2005/03/30 v3.3o English support from the babel system
inputenc.sty    2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
latin1.def    2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
supp-pdf.mkii
nameref.sty    2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
test.out
test.out
translator-basic-dictionary-English.dict
translator-bibliography-dictionary-English.dict
translator-environment-dictionary-English.dict
translator-months-dictionary-English.dict
translator-numbers-dictionary-English.dict
translator-theorem-dictionary-English.dict
```

Comment: Please add `\listfiles` to your input and edit the resulting `*File list*` from the `.log` into the question.

Comment: OK, your file list shows a massively out-of-date `geometry` (from 2000: mine is dates 2010). Look through your log and find the lines where it is loaded: is it part of your distribution or is in a 'local install'? Just editing in the lines where it's loaded might give us a clue.

Comment: OP here -- that was it, Mr. Wright. I feel like a bit of an idiot for not noticing that my \localtexmf, which dates back to the days of manually adding packages, had an ancient copy of geometry in it. But mostly I'm very happy to have this problem banished to the ether! Thanks very much!

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The StackExchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the problem was caused by an old version of a package (geometry), placed in the local tree, was loaded instead of the latest version.